# spring-data-jpa ddl-auto permissions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My project uses spring-data-jpa.

The company stipulates that the test environment and the generated environment database account have only read and write permissions.

I found that when ddl-auto is set to none, the database structure is also changed because there is no permission to cause the service to fail on start. How to set the ddl-auto attribute so that the program does not change the database nor do the check?

> spring-data-jpa
>   document：https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-database-initialization
>
> 10.2. Initialize a Database Using Hibernate You can set spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto explicitly and the standard Hibernate
>   property values are none, validate, update, create, and create-drop.
>   Spring Boot chooses a default value for you based on whether it thinks
>   your database is embedded. It defaults to create-drop if no schema
>   manager has been detected or none in all other cases. An embedded
>   database is detected by looking at the Connection type. hsqldb, h2,
>   and derby are embedded, and others are not. Be careful when switching
>   from in-memory to a ‘real’ database that you do not make assumptions
>   about the existence of the tables and data in the new platform. You
>   either have to set ddl-auto explicitly or use one of the other
>   mechanisms to initialize the database.

Answer (score 0):

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`

**The standard Hibernate property values are: create, update, create-drop, validate and none**:

**create** – Hibernate first drops existing tables, then creates new tables.

**update** – the object model created based on the mappings (annotations or XML) is compared with the existing schema, and then Hibernate updates the schema according to the diff. It never deletes the existing tables or columns even if they are no more required by the application.

**create-drop** – similar to create, with the addition that Hibernate will drop the database after all operations are completed. Typically used for unit testing.

**validate** – Hibernate only validates whether the tables and columns exist, otherwise it throws an exception.

**none** – this value effectively turns off the DDL generation

Comment: When I set it to none, spring-boot-autoconfigure will remove this configuration, it will use the default value update，actually its equals spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Comment: @handong When using none, It mean spring boot does not touch your ddl and you need to create table by your self.